# list comparison between 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
s=[10,10,20,10,10,20]

t=[20,20,10,20,20,30]
```

- frequency of 10 in s is 4 and in t is 1 difference is 3
- frequency of 20 in s is 2 and in t is 4 difference is 2
- frequency of 30 in s is 0 and in t is 1 difference is 1

The number of occurrence of 10,20 and 30 in the two list never differ by more than 3 then return True else return False

How to solve above problem . i am using set and difference function but unable to get expected o/p . can someone provide me hint to solve above problem

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: [Manuel's answer is actually a very fast implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66611934/15387656) [PRMP Smart's answer explains how the logic works.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66611907/15387656)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `collections.Counter` to get amount of each element in a list:

```py
import collections

s = [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20]
t = [20, 20, 10, 20, 20, 30]

collections.Counter(s)
# >> Counter({10: 4, 20: 2})

collections.Counter(t)
# >> Counter({20: 4, 10: 1, 30: 1})

collections.Counter(t)[20]
# >> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using count method of list you can get different

```
>>> s=[10,10,20,10,10,20]
>>> 
>>> t=[20,20,10,20,20,30]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> s.count(10)-t.count(10)
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed smell like homework :D
But just incase you're generally stuck, here it is:

```
s=[10,10,20,10,10,20]
t=[20,20,10,20,20,30]

set_s = set(s)
set_t = set(t)


set_max = set_s if len(set_s) > len(set_t) else set_t

count_dict = {}

for e in set_max:
    if e in s and e in t:
        count_dict[e] = abs(s.count(e) - t.count(e))
    elif e in s:
        count_dict[e] = s.count(e)
    else:
        count_dict[e] = t.count(e)
print(count_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the unique values from both the list combined

```
st = set(s+t)
```

Now, you can find the difference in count:

```
diff={}
for val in st:
    diff[val] = abs(s.count(val) - t.count(val))
print(diff)
```

Output

```
{10: 3, 20: 2, 30: 1}
```

Now, you have a dictionary with the difference of values which you can use as and how you want

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [10,10,10,20,10,20]
t = [20,20,10,20,20,30]
def difference_calc(a,t):
    for i in set(a).union(set(t)): 
        if abs(a.count(i)-t.count(i)) > 3:
           return False
    return True
print(difference_calc(a,t))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Oh thank you :D .. ngl i straight up saw the question and hastily wanted to answer it before anyone did so i quickly whipped out an answer and posted it and then a refresh later i found out i was like fifth XD ... thanks for tip tho :D

Answer (score 0):

The is a function that can solved the question you posted.

```
#  this is a function that solves the problem

def list_diff(s, t):
    # sorting the lists
    s.sort()
    t.sort()

    # dicts for the numbers in s and t
    xs_in_s = {}
    xs_in_t = {}

    # For loop to populate the dicts with the frequencies of the number in s and t
    for xs in s:
        xs_in_s[xs] = s.count(xs)

        # this is to add numbers that are in 's' but not in 't' into 't'
        if xs not in t: xs_in_t[xs] = 0

    for xs in t:
        xs_in_t[xs] = t.count(xs)

        # this is to add numbers that are in 't' but not in 's' into 's'
        if xs not in s: xs_in_s[xs] = 0

    # After these for loops
    # xs_in_s = {10: 4, 20: 2, 30: 0}
    # xs_in_t = {20: 4, 10: 1, 30: 1}


    # to test for the difference of the datas in the two dicts
    # since the keys in 'xs_in_s' is the same as that of 'xs_in_t'
    # any of 'xs_in_s' or 'xs_in_t' can be used

    for x in xs_in_s:
        xs = xs_in_s[x]
        xt = xs_in_t[x]
        difference = xs - xt
        abs_diff = abs(difference)
        if abs_diff > 3: return False

    # the next code will only execute if the 'abs_diff > 3 == False' for all the keys in the dict
    return True

s=[10,10,20,10,10,20]
s1=[10,10,20,10,10,20, 10, 10]

t=[20,20,10,20,20,30]

true = list_diff(s, t)


print(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

> i am using set and difference function

Use a `Counter` difference instead:

```
from collections import Counter

def check(s, t):
    c = Counter(s)
    c.subtract(t)
    return max((c | -c).values()) <= 3
```